# How efficient is it to get integer from standardUserDefaults directly?

Tags: ios, ios4, nsuserdefaults

Might be a stupid question but in our iOS app we're storing an integer for a UI color preference. In drawRect of a custom view, we're currently getting that preference value and using it to set a particular UIColor for some text that is drawn.

I understand that standardUserDefaults values are cached, but is this an inefficient way of doing things? Should we instead add a local ivar to the custom view and pull the preference value on init and then register for a notification when defaults are changed, so the value can be updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted here: [Accessing NSUserDefaults Often](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114641/accessing-nsuserdefaults-often), unless you are optimizing an inner loop that is called a million times per second, you don't need to worry about this at all.

Also it's probably a bad idea to ask yourself such questions, that's called premature optimization and we all know that it's the root of all evil. If you want to know real answers, put all the code in the correct context (so you basically need to have the whole application finished) and use the profiler. In most cases you will see that the bottleneck is where you wouldn't expect it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the time profiler and see where time is being spent in your drawing method. I doubt that getting the value from defaults is a performance bottleneck, compared to any drawing you actually do with the colour itself.

Don't make your code more complicated than it has to be without good reason.